# How to use file system function 'exists' in symfony2?

Tags: symfony

I checked symfony2 API docs [here](http://api.symfony.com/2.1/index.html),

Few File system functions are available in Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem

i used '**mkdir**' and it worked fine but, unable to use '**exists**' function

public Boolean exists(string|array|Traversable $files)

It gives error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function Survey\BlogBundle\Controller\exists()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure it is not

```
bool file_exists ( string $filename )
```

http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-exists.php

---

Looking at the docs I see that there is an exists function. So maybe you have missed to add a use statement

```
use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem;
```

However you can still use `file_exists`

---

Detailed information on how to use filesystem http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/filesystem.html

> New in version 2.1: The Filesystem Component is new to Symfony 2.1.
>   Previously, the Filesystem class was located in the HttpKernel
>   component.

Comment: #artworkad: i used this component Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem and after that 'exists' function but it didn't worked. and FYI i am getting error while using 'exists' function ....

Comment: Did you know it? I am still looking for a solution

Comment: Did you use it from object ? $fs = new Filesystem(); $fs->exists(...)

Comment: #artworkad: just now i got the cause of error. in symfony2 'exists' is not available..'exists' function work in 2.1 version

Comment: #artworkad: ok Thanks for your help.. and i used just now this
  $fs = new Filesystem();
  
  $fs->exists($files)
and its working

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony 5, it does work. It looks like it requires an array for files.

```
use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem;

$fsObject = new Filesystem();
 if ($fsObject->exists(['path/to/file/filename'])){
     //Do something
 }
```