# symfony exists return false even if file exists?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm working with symphony and I'm experiencing one problem.
I want to check if the file exists, and if so update it.
But it's always returning false, like file doesn't exist.

when I try

```
var_dump( $fs->exists('/tmp') );
```

i get true

---

BUT if i do

```
var_dump( $fs->exists('/tmp/test.json') );
```

I get false. 
File actually exists.
Any idea what is the problem?
I even changed permissions to 777, but still same :/

Comment: Check this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907741/how-to-use-file-system-function-exists-in-symfony2)

Answer (score 0):

So based on @Stacked 's comment, it would be like this:

```
var_dump( $fs->file_exists('/tmp/test.json') );
```

Try that.

Answer (score 0):

there was a problem with path.

i added /tmp,containing test.json, directory to /app,

```
$json_file = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/tmp/test.json';
$fs->exists($json_file);
```

not the most impressive solution, but its working.

Comment: In your original post you had "/tmp/test.json", and now you show "/json_files/test.json". How can you expect a good answer...

Comment: ough, sorry i renamed it after. but still it was a problem with path.

ill edit it